# Div page design looks wrong in other resolutions

Tags: css, html

I have a main div of 75% width and 100% height. First of all, the background image doesn't go all the way until the end. Secondly, inside the div, I have two divs, one to the left, one to the right. In the right one I have mostly text, and on smaller resolutions the text gets out of the div, although it has 100% height. I have tried to set pixel heights, but it looks wrong on different resolutions. Any solutions?

Also, the left div seems to have too much space above it in some resolutions, but in others the right one does. I just don't get what I've done wrong.

Here's part of the code. Also, I used a table too, in order to arrange the two lower divs. I know it's probably a mess. :D

CSS:

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Tahoma,sans-serif;
    background-image: url("images/pattern.jpg");
    color: #005200;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}


html {
    background: #47B224;
    height: 100%;
}

.main {
    background: white;
    width: 76%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -38%;
}

.left {
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    width=135px;
}

.right {
    padding: 5px;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
}

table {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

and the rest is like:

```html
<body>
<div class="main">
<table>
    <td>
        <div class="left">
        Content:left
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="right">
        Content:right
        </div>
    </td>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I put your code into a JS fiddle to make it easier for people to help you: http://jsfiddle.net/gEXdr/. I pulled out the `table` because the markup was incorrect (missing tags) and it will just make the layout more difficult.

Comment: I think it is best to show us screen show at regular vs high resolution. It is normal layout will change/mess up if you change the resolution. That is mostly acceptable, unless in your case someone is going to change resolution and you want to make it work for them.

Comment: This is how it looks in 1024x768 resolution. http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/3746/1024x768t.jpg

Comment: @TimMedora If I take out the table it looks something like http://i31.photobucket.com/albums/c377/daryne_/notable.jpg . Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qfsqg/)

I made the changes that I THINK you were describing.  If you are wanting your background to repeat throughout the entire screen then you have to tell it to repeat with `background-repeat: repeat;`  I also made this apply to the `html` tag instead of the `body` tag.

This might have been by design, but to me it looked like you wanted to split the main section into columns in which case you need to use `float: left;` on the left column...again this is just depending on what you were wanting and shouldn't have an effect on anything.

Personally though, I'd gauge what your target audience is and figure out what the minimum resolution is.  From that design to that with your added margins on left our right on higher resolutions.

Comment: Thanks, I put the background in the HTML and that part works. But still, I need to make the white part go all the way down and get rid of the space above the left side. http://i31.photobucket.com/albums/c377/daryne_/print.jpg Also, the margins on left and right seem alright on every resolution I've tried. The bottom is my issue.